# what is the most significant bit and least significant number

Tags: math, binary, calculus

what is the  most significant bit (MSB) and least significant bit (LSB) for, 0.11001 (binary)

is it MSB => 1 = (2 superscript 0) or 1 = (2 superscript -1)

is it LSB => 1 = (2 superscript -5) or 1 = (2 superscript -4)

what is the right method to calculate MSB and LSB, should it shift on decimal point to left to get the MSB.

Comment: Standardly, we don't have any decimal point in binary representation!

Comment: The most significant bit in this representation is the left-most zero. The least significant bit is the right-most one. If you want to ignore trailing and leading zeros, then the most significant bit is the left-most one. However, usually, these terms are used without considering the number's content but only its structure.

Comment: dont we consider the position as above, when I get the MSB = 0 (2 superscript 0) and LSB =1 (2 superscript -5). If ignore the leading zero MSB = 1 (2 superscript 0) and LSB =1 (2 superscript -4). is this correct.